# mySQL query not running delete after Row_Number function as the primary key no longer exists.(i have the primary key column in the new table)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, primary-key, sql-delete

```
WITH idpublisher AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY publisher)
     AS RowNumber
   FROM idpublisher
)
delete FROM idpublisher WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

> **Error Code: 1288. The target table idpublisher of the DELETE is not
> updatable 0.000 sec**

Comment: i have my table idpublisher as updatable but when the query is run on it the new table is not updateable so it does not run the delete method

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh if you have an id autoincrement on the table a simple self join would do the trick. Check the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2sXP7rPxAFEUJ5QHJ9w4v/2

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete/flag obsolete comments. PS [mre] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this, as your code isn't valid

I assume you have an auto_increnet that has a column name of id

Still, this is **very dangerous**, so it should be **tested** on a sample database or dbfidlle

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY publisher)
     AS RowNumber
   FROM idpublisher
)
delete FROM idpublisher WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1)
```

Or use a INNER JOIN

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY publisher)
     AS RowNumber
   FROM idpublisher
)
delete idpublisher FROM idpublisher JOIN CTE ON idpublisher.id = CTE.id WHERE  CTE.RowNumber > 1
```

Comment: Thanku the first code solved my problem.